# Pentaho MongoDBInput Java integration

Tags: pentaho

I have a simple pentaho formation with MongoDBInput connected with JSON Output. I am able to fetch json while i see preview in Pentaho Design studio but as I try to integrate with java, and run the transformation, its throwing error -

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException:  Error reading
>   object from XML file
>
> Unable to load step info from XML step
>   nodeorg.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleStepLoaderException:  Unable
>   to load class for step/plugin with id [MongoDbInput]. Check if the
>   plugin is available in the plugins subdirectory of the Kettle
>   distribution.
>
> Unable to load class for step/plugin with id [MongoDbInput]. Check if
>   the plugin is available in the plugins subdirectory of the Kettle
>   distribution.

My code is:

```
 import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment;
import org.pentaho.di.core.util.EnvUtil;
import org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta;
import org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans;
import org.pentaho.di.core.*;
import org.pentaho.di.core.exception.*;

public class KettleConnector {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws KettleException, IOException{

        KettleEnvironment.init(false);

        EnvUtil.environmentInit();

        TransMeta transMeta = new TransMeta("D:\\mangoes.ktr");

        Trans trans = new Trans(transMeta);

        trans.execute(null); // You can pass arguments instead of null.

        trans.waitUntilFinished();

        Result r = trans.getResult();

        List<RowMetaAndData> rowsResult = r.getRows();
        System.out.println(trans.getTransMeta());

        if (trans.getErrors() > 0) {

        throw new RuntimeException();

        }

    }

}
```

It works fine for mysql transformations.

I have included mongo-2.4jar and mongo-java-driver-2.7.2.jar

still am facing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you are adding VM argument while running:

> ```
> -DKETTLE_PLUGIN_BASE_FOLDERS=D:/LOCATION/data-integration/plugins
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB steps are Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) plugins. What version of PDI are you using? If you are using 4.4.0, then you will need the Big Data plugin, which contains the MongoDB steps. From where you launch your application, you'll need a plugins/steps folder containing the contents of the Big Data plugin (the pentaho-big-data-plugin folder). Then your call to KettleEnvironment.init() will load the plugins and you will have access to the MongoDB steps.

Answer (score 0):

Matt..I am using pentaho kettle 5.1. What jars need to be included from the plugins folder for the Mongodb steps to work. I have included everything from plugins/pentaho-mongodb-plugin?

Still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Well...figured out with Matt's help.
Though this answer doesn't fit well with how java WAR files are designed, essentially you need the entire plugins folder passed in as an argument (-D) to your app server. Here's an example

-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_BASE_FOLDERS=/Users/user1/Documents/pdi-ce-5.1.0/data-integration/plugins